# Power query replacing values

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

I'm replacing values in Power query. I replaced the correct values with a formula that was created in excel, but now I see that Power query doesn't work like that:/

[the idea is to replace the value "½" to get the values as in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up8Nz.png)

THE NON-WORKING FORMULA IS THIS:

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Odstranjeni stolpci","½","=Value(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+1))-0.5)",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1", "Column2", ..............

If someone can help me resolve this, it would help A LOT!

Comment: Is the tag 'excel formula' appropriate for this Q??

Answer (score 0):

Given your row of textual data, here is how I would change it to numbers in PQ, assuming you have several rows of data, and that you might have any of the "fractions" in the data: `¼`, `½`, `¾`.

In the code below, to do the multiple replacements:

- Convert the text string to a **List**
- `List.ReplaceMatchingItems` allows the replacement of multiple different items with different replacements in a single line of code.
- We also replace the `space` that you have between the number and the fraction with *null*
- Then combine the List back into a text string, and convert it to a number.
- *If your fractional number is part of a longer string that contains spaces, you will need to be sure you only insert the nulls in the right place.*

**Source**
[image]
**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WOrRXSUfJTOHQHiBlqgDhAbGxwqF9SrE60UpGMI6OkglElTlElaGBUmwsAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t, Column3 = _t, Column4 = _t, Column5 = _t]),
    typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, Text.Type})),

//Replace all values
    colXformOps = List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(typed), (cn)=>{cn, each Number.FromText(
                            Text.Combine(
                                List.ReplaceMatchingItems(
                                    Text.ToList(_),{{"¼",".25"},{"½",".5"},{"¾",".75"},{" ",null}})
                )),Number.Type}),
    replTbl = Table.TransformColumns(typed, colXformOps)
                
in
  replTbl
```

**Results**
[image]